# Are there any alternatives for graph protocol?

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, decentralized-applications

I'm building a Dapp and I want to index records to make queries on them. I see the only option is using [graph protocol](https://thegraph.com/en/). Are there any other options?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are, check out Moralis!

https://docs.moralis.io/streams-api/evm

Answer (score 0):

What you are likely asking is what services there exist to build custom indexers you can expose to the web frontend.

Here are some

- [TheGraph](https://thegraph.com/)
- [Subquery](https://subquery.network/)
- [Superchain](https://www.superchain.network/)

Furthermore there are some proprietary software-as-a-service offerings,  but they go against the ethos of Dapp. This is because if you use a proprietary and private service provider you application cannot be decentralised by definition.